# i can't closing my app with back button because onKeyDown() method

Tags: android, kotlin, event-handling, event-listener

i made a code to run event handler, but i got a problem that i can't close my app with back button

```
package bahrudin.bagus.inputevents

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

// if i use this method, then i can't close app with back button
// otherwise, if I don't use this method, then I can close the app with back button
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Volume Down Key Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Volume Up Key Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Back Key Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return true
    }
```

how can i close my app while still using this method?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use change the KEYCODE_BACK code into this

```
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Back Key Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    // finish() //one of these 2, not both, it usually depends on the behavior you need, since you can override back press to a desired behavior as well
    // super.onBackPressed()
}
```